# Cannot compile UWP project: App package... manifest validation error

Tags: uwp

### Update

As noted in `Remarks item 3` below. The following error is caused when I add the namespace `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"` and value `recap` in the attribute  `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap"` of project's `Package.appmanifest` file.

And the error goes away when I rollback the above two changes.

### Original Post

[Problem still exists with the addition of the above values - that I do want to add unless someone suggest a better solution]

In my `UWP` project of `VS2017`, I get the following compile error on file `...\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml`:

> > Validation error. error 80080204: App manifest validation error: The app manifest XML must be valid: Line 2, Column 427, Reason: System error: -2142175169.

**My Package.appmanifest file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap">

...
```

**...\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap build">
  <!--
    THIS PACKAGE MANIFEST FILE IS GENERATED BY THE BUILD PROCESS.

    Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.

    For more information on package manifest files, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241727
  -->
....
....
```

**Remarks**

1. The error seems related to missing a namespace alias value in `IgnorableNamespaces` attribute. Now, in `Package.appmanifest file` it's `...IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap">`. And in `...\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml` it's `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap build">`. So `AppxManifest.xml` in Debug folder is generating an extra namespace with alias `build`. But I don't know why Visual Studio does it despite the fact that I've not declared in `Package.appmanifest` file.
2. Project was compiling fine before I added an extra namespace `xmlns:rescap="....."` to `Package.appmanifest` file. Moreover, even when I copy/paste the `xmlns:build="...."` namespace from `Debug\AppxManifest.xml` to `Package.appmanifest` I still get the exact same error
3. I tried cleaning the solution and re-compiling but same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you have a typo in the `IgnorableNamespaces` attribute:

```
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp recap"
```

Should be

```
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"
```

Note the missing "s" character. It is a abbreviation of "**res**tricted **cap**abilities"

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo and (more importantly) explaining why it's `rescap` instead of `recap`. It's working now.

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy coding!

Comment: Correct answer, but please not that the string doesn't have to be `rescap` - it could be `banana` for all the computer cares. It just has to be used consistently :)